# awk: runtime error - Compatility between zsh config on MacOS Catalina and zsh config on Debian Buster

Tags: awk, zsh, macos-catalina, zshrc, debian-buster

I have a zsh config on MacOS Catalina which works well. No, I would like to get the same but for Debian 10 Buster.

The issue occurs in the using of function for PROMPT that displays pink slashes that separate the PATH current working where directories are in blue.

On MacOS, I do it like this (into my .zshrc) :

```
# Path with colorized forward slash
slash_color() {
dirs | awk -F "/" '{ blue="%{\033[38;5;75m%}"; \
                     pink="%{\033[38;5;206m%}"; \
                     for (i=1; i<NF; i++) \
                      printf blue $i pink "/"; \
                     printf blue $NF pink; \
                   }';
}

# Prompt final
PROMPT=$'%F{13}|%F{green}%n@%F{cyan}%m%F{13}|%f%T%F{13}|$(slash_color)%F{13}|%F{7} '
```

The result looks like for PROMPT :

[image: zsh prompt for MacOS Catalina]

Now, on Debian Buster, I have copied the ~/.zshrc from MacOS Catalina.

and **when PROMPT is displayed, the PATH of current working directory is not displayed (empty)** and I get the following error :

```
awk: run time error: not enough arguments passed to printf("%{%}~%{%}/")
    FILENAME="-" FNR=1 NR=1
```

I don't know why I have this error on Debian and not on MacOS. I suspect this is due to a difference on the working of my `slash_color()` function but I don't understand the origin.

It seems that a variable is missing in Debian version for `awk`, but I can't see which one.

Comment: You pass `%` to `printf`....

Comment: You don't need the semicolons or the backslashes at the end of the lines in the awk script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not do: `printf something`. Always do `printf "%s", something`. The awk errors, because you passed invalid `printf` format specifiers `%{` and `%}`, yet you did not pass any arguments. Do:

```
printf "%s%s%s/", blue, $i, pink;
```

I think you can just:

```
{gsub("/", pink "/" blue)}1
```

Comment: Right. And in fact something like `awk 'BEGIN{blue="%{\033[38;5;75m%}"; pink="%{\033[38;5;206m%}"} {gsub("/",pink"&"blue)} 1'` or `awk 'BEGIN{blue="%{\033[38;5;75m%}"; pink="%{\033[38;5;206m%}"} {gsub("[^/]+",blue"&"pink)} 1'` is probably all that's required.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a pre-command hook and simple parameter expansion instead of forking various external programs.

```
precmd () {
    bar='%F{13}|'
    prompt="$bar%F{green}%n@%F{cyan}%m$bar%f%T$bar%F{75}"
    prompt+=${PWD:gs./.%F{206}/%F{75}}
    prompt+="$bar%F{7} "
}
```

Add this to your `.zshrc` file, and `prompt` will be reset prior to displaying it, rather than embedding a shell function in the prompt itself.

`PWD` is the current working directory. The `gs.---.---` expansion modifier replaces each `/` with `%F{206}/%F{75}`, using `zsh`'s own color escape sequences rather than using raw ANSI escape sequences.